# Why I can't update to latest version of Query.jl Package?

Tags: package, julia

Going to GitHub I noticed that `Query.jl` 4 days ago [released a `v0.10.0` version](https://github.com/queryverse/Query.jl/releases).

In its require I can read it specifies Julia 0.7 as minimum version.

In both Julia 0.7 or 1.0 however I am stuck on `v0.9.3`.
Even if I `add Query#master` I go to `v0.9.3+ #master (https://github.com/queryverse/Query.jl.git)`:

[image]

What's blocking my system to get the latest `Query.jl` version and how can I force to get it ? (I already tried `resolve`)

**EDIT:**
Now that the pull request has been merged I can update to v0.10.0

Comment: The release has not been merged to the registry yet, see https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl/pull/17518

Comment: I was able to install v0.10.0+ via `add Query#master`. If you already added previous version using master branch, there might be an issue with julia retrieving an updated repository and still using cached version. I'll try to replicate and if this turns out to be the problem, then report an issue.

Comment: @Hckr Thanks, I added a screenshot..